# TF30040 after database server migration

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2008-r2

we've attempted a database server migration for a TFS2012 install (source & destination db servers are both 2008r2). We backed up the databases from the old server and successfully restored them onto the new one. I did a database compare between the two after we'd restored and all the expected objects were transferred. However, when I run the tfsconfig remapdbs command I get a TF30040 error.

Most of the examples / help I've found so far relates to TFS2010 rather than 2012.

Any thoughts on what to check for would be greatly appreciated as we're otherwise a bit stuck on the wrong database hardware.

thanks Andy

Answer (score 0):

If you backup and restore with the TFS Management application, it does a bit more than using an SQL database backup - so if you went that route, or if the automatic restore had a glitch, there will be some manual steps you may need to apply.

In particular, the [database needs to be stamped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252443.aspx) with the ID of the TFS server that it is being used by, and you may also need to [remap the databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349262.aspx) to get them linked to the server properly.

Important: Please do some research on the above commands before you try executing anything. You may find the [migration docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx) helpful. Hopefully this will give you a good starting point to find a remedy for your the problem, but please be careful to understand the instructions before you go ahead. The most important thing is to keep your backup so in the worst case you can still rebuild it and have another go if anything gets broken.

Comment: We went the manual route as we had to hand the restore process off to our outsourced db support. It seems it might be worth trying via the TFS admin route instead if it does a few extra "hidden" steps.

We did go through the migration docs you mentioned above and it was at the remap databases step that things fell over with the TF30040 error.

Comment: In addition to this; In the migration docs info about using the restore tool says "In order to restore the TFS databases using the restore tool, you must install but not configure TFS on the new data-tier server, and then use the restore function in the Scheduled Backups node."
Does that mean we need to run out TFS installation again, but tell it to use / create databases on the new server but then do nothing with it. Then use TFS admin to restore and it'll in effect overwrite the "base" install ?

Comment: If you can still backup from tfs managenent on your old server, I'd try using that first.

Comment: We're just moving the existing database to a different database server. The TFS services etc., run on a different machine. So we still have access to all the bits we need. The question really was around to "restore" it to the new server via TFSAdmin it looks like we have to "install" TFS again onto the new server but just the database part so that it sets things up. Then when we restore the additional security etc., will all be in place ? It's a PITA as we have to stop using the old system whilst we backup, move and restore.